# Cubic Residues (Number Theory)

Tags: number-theory

I'm trying to figure out a conjecture about cubic residues and I need some examples

Any examples $a,b$ so that neither $a$ or $b$ is a cubic residue $\mod 19$, but $ab$ is a cubic residue modulo $19$?

Any examples where none of $a, b$ or $ab$ are cubic residues?

Comment: Have you found a primitive root mod $19$?

Comment: When looking for quadratic residues you usually exclude $p=2$ (because everything here is a quadratic residue). When looking for cubic residues you will have to make a similar condition...since for some primes EVERYTHING is a cubic residue (e.g. $p=3,5,11,...$). The primes that are left over will satisfy results similar to quadratic residues (there will be $\frac{p-1}{3}$ cubic residues, however the multiplicativity will fail but there will still be SOME group structure etc).

Answer (score 3):

Neither $2^6$ or $2^9$ are $\equiv 1\pmod{19}$, hence it follows that $g=2$ is a generator for $\mathbb{F}_{19}^*$ and:

$$\left\{ g^\color{purple}{0},g^3,g^6,g^9,g^{12},g^{15}\right\} = \color{purple}{\{1,8,7,18,11,12\}}, $$
$$\left\{ g^\color{red}{1},g^4,g^7,g^{10},g^{13},g^{16}\right\} = \color{red}{\{{2},16,14,17,3,5\}}, $$
$$\left\{ g^\color{blue}{2},g^5,g^8,g^{11},g^{14},g^{17}\right\} = \color{blue}{\{4,{13},9,15,6,10\}}, $$
so, for instance, neither $2$ or $13$ are cubic residues, but:
$$ \color{red}{2}\cdot\color{blue}{13}\equiv \color{purple}{7}\pmod{19}$$
and $7$ is a cubic residue. More generally, the multiplication table of colours is the following:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|}\cdot &\color{purple}{\bigstar} &\color{red}{\bigstar} & \color{blue}{\bigstar} \\ \hline \color{purple}{\bigstar} &\color{purple}{\bigstar} &\color{red}{\bigstar} &\color{blue}{\bigstar} \\ \hline \color{red}{\bigstar} &\color{red}{\bigstar} &\color{blue}{\bigstar} &\color{purple}{\bigstar} \\ \hline \color{blue}{\bigstar} &\color{blue}{\bigstar} &\color{purple}{\bigstar} &\color{red}{\bigstar}\\ \hline\end{array}$$
and the colour group, not by chance, is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/(3\mathbb{Z})$.

Answer (score 1):

take any prime $p$ that is congruent to $1\bmod 3$. The multiplicative group $\bmod p$ is isomorphic to the group $\mathbb Z_{p-1}=\{e,a,1^{1},a^2\dots a^{p-2}\}$ and hence the cubic residues are the elements with exponents that are multiples of three. So for example $a^1\cdot a^4=a^5$ wont be a cubic residue. And any non-cubic residue squared won't be a cubic residue.

To give an example consider $\bmod 19$,we have that $10$ is a primitive root.

We have $10\cdot10^4\equiv 10\cdot 6\equiv 3$ which is not a cubic residue.

We have $10\cdot 10\equiv 5$ which is not a cubic resiude.

Comment: For the other part of the Question, $a,b$ not cubic residues but $ab$ is a cubic residue, we could let $b=a^{-1}$ so $ab=1$.

Comment: Oh yeah, I just answered the other part. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

The cubic residues $\pmod {19}$ are ${1, 7, 8, 11, 12, 18}$. See Jack D'Aurizio's answer, the product of a single "red" residue with a "blue" residue will yield a cubic residue. In particular for all primes $p=1 \pmod 3$ but not $p=1 \pmod 9$, if $c$ is an element with order $(p-1)/3 \pmod p$ (and therefore a cubic residue), and $r$ is a solution to $r^2+r+1=0 \pmod p$, then $ab$ is a cubic residue $\pmod p$ if and only if $a=rs^2$ for some integer $s$ and $b=r^2t^2$ for some integer $t$.